# Problems Implementing a QR Code Generator with Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, zxing

I'm having some trouble with an implementation of the ZXing.Net.Mobile (Android) implementation in Xamarin Forms. I have the following class in my Android project which implements the IBarcodeWriter interface (which is in my Shared Project). The application isn't throwing any errors but it isn't showing an image when added into a stacklayout with `DependencyService.Get<IBarcodeWriter> ().GetImage()`

This is the class from my Droid project:

```
namespace SmartCart {

public class BarcodeGenerator : IBarcodeWriter
{
    public BarcodeGenerator () {}
    public Image image = new Image();
    public byte[] bitmapBytes;

    public String qrData (String s) {
        return s;
    }

    public void CreateBarcode () {

        image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => 
            {
                var writer = new BarcodeWriter 
                {
                    Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
                    Options = new EncodingOptions 
                    {
                        Height = 200,
                        Width = 600
                    }
                };

                var bitmapBytes = writer.Write ("Encode this to QRCode");
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bitmapBytes);
                ms.Position = 0;
                return ms;

            });
    }

    public Image GetImage() {
        return image;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use following method to generate a QR-Code. (look at the `bitmap.Compress` row, maybe that solves your Problem):

```
public byte[] GenerateQrImage(string content, int width, int height)
{
    var options = new QrCodeEncodingOptions
    {
        Height = height,
        Width = width,
        Margin = 0,
        PureBarcode = true
    };

    var writer = new BarcodeWriter
    {
        Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
        Options = options
    };

    // Generate bitmap
    var bitmap = writer.Write(content);
    if (bitmap != null)
    {
        // Get bytes from bitmap
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

**Edit:** It turns out, that the problem may be a wrong nuget package. use [this package](http://nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net) to generate the qr-code

Comment: Any idea why it wouldn't be picking up the .Compress method? I'd already tried that but I was given an error somewhere along the lines of "byte[] does not contain a definition for 'Compress'".

Comment: Ah. I think you installed the wrong nuget package. My `writer.Write(content);` method returns a Bitmap-Object. I used this nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net/